# How to optimize this query using model in Laravel

Tags: laravel, join, inner-join, laravel-models

Actual Requirement.
Select * from User, Student_basicinfo,Student_programs where
User.id=student_basicinfo.student_id,user.id=student_programs.student_id;

I want to use this query with model approach but i don't know how.

there 3 different tables
student_id is primary in user table but in other tables is as foreign key.

```
    public function getdata()
{
   $users= DB::table('Student__Basicinfos')
    ->join('Student__Programs', 'Student__Basicinfos.student_id', '=', 'Student__Programs.student_id')
  //  ->join('Student__Academics', 'Student__Basicinfos.student_id', '=', 'Student__Academics.student_id')
    //->join('Upload', 'Student__Basicinfos.student_id', '=', 'Upload.student_id')
    ->select ('Student__Basicinfos.student_id','student__Basicinfos.student_name','student__Basicinfos.father_name',
    'student__Basicinfos.gender','student__Basicinfos.domicile_province','student__Basicinfos.present_address','student__Basicinfos.present_mobile',
    'student__Basicinfos.student_email','student__Basicinfos.created_at',
    'Student__Programs.student_status','Student__Programs.program1','Student__Programs.program2','Student__Programs.awaiting_result')
    ->orderByRaw('student_id DESC')
    ->get();

    return view('alldata',compact('users'));
}
```

Comment: Watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HadES55O4Wk). It will be of great help.

Comment: you have to create Laravel Model for each table and then make relation between. Video above will help

Comment: Didnt get my point from video and that was not mus clear in a beginner can you more clear

Comment: read the doc, https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships